# Adding Button to Pivot Chart Tools Ribbon/Toolbar

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a button to the ribbon that will be assigned to a macro. I know how to create a button via XML and also how to assign it to a macro, but I am having difficulty identifying the correct control ID/command bar. I would like to add a button to the "Pivot Chart Tools" menu. I am able to do this without VBA, by going to "Customize the Ribbon". However, I cannot figure out how to access it through VBA. I have banged my head against this for hours. Below is a sample of some code that I've tried. I've also tried several other pieces of code, but none seem to point me in the direction of the desired toolbar. I have also posted a picture of the toolbar in question. I am trying to add a button to: Pivot Chart Tools -> Analyze -> Data. The button would be grouped in the Data section there, at the same level as "Change Source Data" and "Refresh". Thank you for your help.

```
Public Sub ListToolbars()
'Code used to attempt to pinpoint correct toolbar

Dim cmdBar As CommandBar
Dim cmdBarButton As CommandBarControl
Dim lr As Long

lr = 1

Set cmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Pivot Chart Popup")
'Loop through
For Each cmdBarButton In cmdBar.Controls

        Cells(lr, 4).Value = cmdBarButton.Caption
        Cells(lr, 5).Value = cmdBarButton.ID
        Cells(lr, 6).Value = cmdBarButton.Type

    lr = lr + 1
Next cmdBarButton
End Sub

Public Sub BET_ShowCommandBarNames()
'Code used to identify all bars
Dim cmdBar As CommandBar
Dim lrownumber As Long
Dim z As Integer

Dim commandButton As CommandBarButton
Dim popButton As CommandBarPopup

   Workbooks.Add
   lrownumber = 1
   For Each cmdBar In CommandBars
      Range("A" & lrownumber).Value = cmdBar.Name
      Select Case cmdBar.Type
         Case msoBarTypeNormal
               Range("B" & lrownumber).Value = "Toolbar"
               If cmdBar.Name = "Borders" Then cmdBar.Visible = True
         Case msoBarTypeMenuBar
               Range("B" & lrownumber).Value = "Menu Bar"
         Case msoBarTypePopup
               Range("B" & lrownumber).Value = "zShortcut"

      End Select
      lrownumber = lrownumber + 1
   Next cmdBar
   Columns("A:B").Select
   Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Key2:=Range("A1"), Order2:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: My initial thought would be why are you trying to access this through VBA? you can assign a macro to it so presumably you are attempting to do something with the ribbon? If so, what are you attempting to do?

Comment: @Zac hi Zac, I have created my own pivot table drill down feature that utilizes the chart sheet module. I think it would be too much to ask the users of my model to use the built in shortcut.. F10? I think? I don't work with savvy people. Therefore I wanted to add a button there which they could see and click. It seems like we are not able to access built in groups however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to add a button to a built-in group.  So you'll have to create your own custom group using XML.  Try something like this...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <contextualTabs>
              <tabSet idMso="TabSetPivotChartTools" >
                  <tab idMso="TabPivotChartToolsAnalyze" >
                     <group id="MyCustomGroup1" label="My Custom Group" insertAfterMso="GroupPivotChartData" >
                        <button id="customButton1" label="Click Me" 
                            size="large" onAction="Macro1" imageMso="AppointmentColor3" 
                            supertip="This is a super tip..." />
                     </group>
                  </tab>
               </tabSet>
        </contextualTabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, I was afraid this would be the answer. I am familiar with how to create a custom group. Will probably go this route today. Thanks for your response. I'll mark as solved in a few, giving a bit more time